# Why is the residue defined on a circle in complex analysis?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

I'm confused by the definition of the residue, which is as follows (from the book *Complex Variables and Applications* by James Ward Brown).

[image]

I don't know why the author restricted $z$ in $0<|z-z_0|<R_2$.

The Laurent series does not need this restriction, which are as follows.

[image]

[image]

**In other words, $R_1$ in the definition of the Laurent series doesn't need to be zero, but in the definition of the residue it is zero.**

I don't know why. I think the condition $R_1=0$ seems to be redundant and unnecessary in the definition of the residue. I think we could also get the definition of residue without this condition

So I'm very confused about this.

I'd appreciate it if you could help with my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about poles and residues is that a function can have more than one pole.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1718433/139123), in which there is a diagram representing a function with poles at $z_1,$ $z_2,$ $z_3,$ and $z_4.$
For convenience, here's a copy of that diagram:

[image: Contour around four poles of a function]

The definition of the Laurent series, which only requires the function to be analytic on $R_1 < \lvert z - z_0 \rvert < R_2,$
allows us to apply that definition to the outer contour $C$ in this diagram.
If that definition required $R_1 = 0$ then it could not be applied to that contour, since there's no punctured disk containing $C$ on which the function is analytic.
(You can take care of one pole by centering the disk at one of the poles, say $z_1,$ but then there are still three other poles in the punctured disk that you can't get rid of without losing at least part of $C$.)

But if we *don't* set $R_1 = 0$ in the definition of the residue around *a single point*, then we could use either the contour $C$ in the diagram above or the contour $C_r(z_1)$ to define the residue of $z_1.$
And the problem with that is that these two contour integrals are not equal.

If you take a contour integral in an arbitrary annulus
$R_1 < \lvert z - z_0 \rvert < R_2$ around an isolated singular point $z_0,$ you're not necessarily getting the residue of $z_0$;
if $R_1 > 0$ you're actually getting the combined residues of $z_0$ and *every other* isolated singular point in the disk $\lvert z - z_0 \rvert \leq R_1.$

Setting $R_1 = 0$ in the definition of the residue of a point $z_0$ ensures that we're getting the reside of $z_0$ alone and not the combined residues of $z_0$ and any other nearby singular point.